# libbitcoin library build error on linux

Tags: linux, cryptocurrency

I got latest from github repo from 
https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin

Already built https://github.com/libbitcoin/secp256k1

However, this build error seems to indicate that the two repos HEADs are out of sync.

```
  ...
  CXX      src/wallet/parse_encrypted_keys/src_libbitcoin_la-parse_encrypted_private.lo
  CXX      src/wallet/parse_encrypted_keys/src_libbitcoin_la-parse_encrypted_public.lo
  CXX      src/wallet/parse_encrypted_keys/src_libbitcoin_la-parse_encrypted_token.lo
  CXXLD    src/libbitcoin.la
copying selected object files to avoid basename conflicts...
  CXX      examples/examples_libbitcoin_examples-main.o
  CXXLD    examples/libbitcoin_examples
src/.libs/libbitcoin.so: undefined reference to `secp256k1_ecdsa_recover'
src/.libs/libbitcoin.so: undefined reference to `secp256k1_ecdsa_sign_recoverable'
src/.libs/libbitcoin.so: undefined reference to `secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_serialize_compact'
src/.libs/libbitcoin.so: undefined reference to `secp256k1_ecdsa_recoverable_signature_parse_compact'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2185: examples/libbitcoin_examples] Error 1
```

Also, running git tag on secp256k1 does not return anything, so it is impossible to figure out what commit on secp256k1 is compatible with what commit on libbitcoin.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the maintainers of the library?

Comment: I am also trying to download it, did you manage to install it?